# Make views/text fit the screen on different android devices

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I am trying to make a 24 hour sidebar menu. But not all numbers fit on every screen. Does anyone know a good approach for me to fix this issue so all the numbers show

**Here is some of my code on how i am doing it right now.**

**Single item**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/car_history_sidemenu_item"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:padding="3dp"

          android:textSize="14sp" />
```

**The layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
          <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/car_history_map_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/history_side_index"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/history_side_index"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
          </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/history_side_index"
            android:background="#c3c3c3"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"


            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code**

```
  protected void setupFastScrollList()
  {
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.history_side_index);

    TextView textView;

    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
      textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.car_history_sidemenu_item,null);
      textView.setText("" + i);
      linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
  }
```

Do i have to scale everything on runtime or is there a smart way by XML to automatically scale the numbers to fit on every device screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read Google's article about Supporting Multiple Screens.

Stable Link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I read a little from the link. Going to read more from it. But i have a question that maybe you can asnwer. I tried to add layout-hdp and layout-mdpi. But both my phones uses the same hpdi layout even tho in my opinion one of them have a larger screen

Comment: Nevermind, found my problem. I did not consider that the other phone was xhdpi